# Python задачка "Всё ограниченно"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно посчитать количество битов равных 1 в числе переведенном в двоичную систему, допустим число 13 , в битовом вариаинте 13 = 1101, ответ будет 3. У меня получилось написать код, который считает количество битов, но не проходит, я не особо понял условие задачи, поэтому условия оставляю на английском.

Числа в промежутке от 0 до 2^32

In your code you cannot have non-whitespace substrings of length greater than one with the exception of the following:int(,print(,input()

[![Задание][1]][1]

```
n=int(input())
bin_n = []
bin_n.append(bin(n))
count = 0
for i in bin_n:
    for j in i:
        if j == '1':
            count+=1
print(count)
```

Comment: судя по всему вы совсем не вкурили условие. "количество бит" = количество информации, и вычисляется оно как log2(x) с округлением в большую сторону. Вы считаете в исходнике количество бит,  установленных в единицу. это уже другая история. Огрызок задания говорит об условиях наличия непробельных подстрок, но условие опять же только частично.

Comment: Нет, у меня решение правильное, но не проходит тест кейсы, потому что я "не вкурил" условие. In this task you have to count the number of set bits (1) in binary representation of a number. @SergeyTatarincev

Comment: может числа отрицательные подают на вход? ничего о тесте не сказано?

Comment: @Zhihar От 0 до 2^32

Comment: Дай ссылку на проверяльщик

Comment: Помимо самой задачи исходный код должен удовлетворять второму условию. Т.е. никаких `for`, а тем более `bin` в коде быть не должно)

Comment: Отличная задача! Я решил :) Как только дадут ссылку на проверяльщик и проверю, то выложу код.

Comment: 2^32 включается?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В коде нельзя иметь последовательности букв и прочих символов длиннее 1 символа, за исключением перечисленных. Отсюда следует: переменным давать имена из одной буквы и можно пользоваться только арифметическими операторами. Например:

```
n = input()
s = int( n )
r = 0

d = s % 2
s = int( s / 2 )
r = r + d
d = s % 2
s = int( s / 2 )
r = r + d
d = s % 2
s = int( s / 2 )
r = r + d
d = s % 2
s = int( s / 2 )
r = r + d
d = s % 2
s = int( s / 2 )
r = r + d
d = s % 2
s = int( s / 2 )
r = r + d
d = s % 2
s = int( s / 2 )
r = r + d
d = s % 2
s = int( s / 2 )
r = r + d
d = s % 2
s = int( s / 2 )
r = r + d
d = s % 2
s = int( s / 2 )
r = r + d
d = s % 2
s = int( s / 2 )
r = r + d
d = s % 2
s = int( s / 2 )
r = r + d
d = s % 2
s = int( s / 2 )
r = r + d
d = s % 2
s = int( s / 2 )
r = r + d
d = s % 2
s = int( s / 2 )
r = r + d
d = s % 2
s = int( s / 2 )
r = r + d
d = s % 2
s = int( s / 2 )
r = r + d
d = s % 2
s = int( s / 2 )
r = r + d
d = s % 2
s = int( s / 2 )
r = r + d
d = s % 2
s = int( s / 2 )
r = r + d
d = s % 2
s = int( s / 2 )
r = r + d
d = s % 2
s = int( s / 2 )
r = r + d
d = s % 2
s = int( s / 2 )
r = r + d
d = s % 2
s = int( s / 2 )
r = r + d
d = s % 2
s = int( s / 2 )
r = r + d
d = s % 2
s = int( s / 2 )
r = r + d
d = s % 2
s = int( s / 2 )
r = r + d
d = s % 2
s = int( s / 2 )
r = r + d
d = s % 2
s = int( s / 2 )
r = r + d
d = s % 2
s = int( s / 2 )
r = r + d
d = s % 2
s = int( s / 2 )
r = r + d
d = s % 2
s = int( s / 2 )
r = r + d
print( r )
```

Comment: Я бы заюзал `//`, если б было можно =)

Comment: ах, блин, точно!

Comment: @vp_arth тогда так

Comment: Спасибо, работает.

Answer (score 2):

> In your code you cannot have non-whitespace substrings of length
> greater than one with the exception of the
> following:int(,print(,input()

Простейшим решением этой головоломки могут быть 32 копии следующего блока:

```
r = r + ( ( a & 1 ) > 0 )
a = int( a / 2 )
```

`( ( a & 1 )  > 0 )` - это аналог `a % 2`, только без деления.
Прямая проверка того, что последний бит включен.
Хотя, можно использовать и деление.

---

```
a = int( input() )

r = 0

# 0
r = r + ( ( a & 1 ) > 0 )
a = int( a / 2 )

# 1
r = r + ( ( a & 1 ) > 0 )
a = int( a / 2 )

# 2
r = r + ( ( a & 1 ) > 0 )
a = int( a / 2 )

# 3
r = r + ( ( a & 1 ) > 0 )
a = int( a / 2 )

# ...

# 32
r = r + ( ( a & 1 ) > 0 )
a = int( a / 2 )

print( r )
```

Comment: блин, ну я тоже тогда свое выложу :)

Comment: ``==`` тоже нельзя :)

Comment: Аха, упс, как говорится

Comment: Нашёл вариантик)

Comment: Хехе ) ........

Answer (score 1):

Надо уже как-то оптимизировать:

```
h = 2 * 8 * 8
m = h - 1
b = [ 0 , 1 , 1 , 2 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 3 , 3 , 4 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 3 , 3 , 4 , 2 , 3 , 3 , 4 , 3 , 4 , 4 , 5 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 3 , 3 , 4 , 2 , 3 , 3 , 4 , 3 , 4 , 4 , 5 , 2 , 3 , 3 , 4 , 3 , 4 , 4 , 5 , 3 , 4 , 4 , 5 , 4 , 5 , 5 , 6 , 1 , 2 , 2 , 3 , 2 , 3 , 3 , 4 , 2 , 3 , 3 , 4 , 3 , 4 , 4 , 5 , 2 , 3 , 3 , 4 , 3 , 4 , 4 , 5 , 3 , 4 , 4 , 5 , 4 , 5 , 5 , 6 , 2 , 3 , 3 , 4 , 3 , 4 , 4 , 5 , 3 , 4 , 4 , 5 , 4 , 5 , 5 , 6 , 3 , 4 , 4 , 5 , 4 , 5 , 5 , 6 , 4 , 5 , 5 , 6 , 5 , 6 , 6 , 7 ]
s = int( input() )
t = int( s / h )
u = int( t / h )
v = int( u / h )
w = int( v / h )
print( b [ s & m ] + b [ t & m ] + b [ u & m ] + b [ v & m ] + b [ w & m ] )
```

Answer (score 0):

у вас не код, а тихий ужас

**вариант 1:**

не проще ли сделать так:

```
value = int(input())

count = 0
while value > 0:
    count += value % 2
    value //= 2

print(count)
```

1. получить ввод от пользователя
2. перевести его в число
3. перевести побитово в двоичный вид (деление числа по модулю 2 даёт текущий бит, деление нацело на 2 уменьшает число)
4. подсчитать биты равные 1 (просто увеличиваем счетчик текущим битом - он или 1 или 0, 0 сумму не увеличивает)

**вариант 2:**

если же делать через строки как вы, тогда вот вам вариант вообще в 1 строку:

```
print(bin(int(input()))[2:].count('1'))
```

1. получить ввод от пользователя
2. перевести его в число
3. преобразовать число в hex представление в виде строки
4. отрезать первые 2 символа (в них содержится `0b` - указатель, что строка это число в двоичном представлении)
5. подсчитать кол-во `1`

Comment: к сожалению не проходит , ошибка "Forbidden expresion", тоже пытался сделать так как вы

Comment: можно `0b` не обрезать

Comment: приведите тогда условие задачи

Comment: @Danis, можно :), это я что-то разошелся, а если надо 0 подсчитать, то можно просто потом -1 сделать

Comment: In this task you have to count the number of set bits (1) in binary representation of a number.
In your code you cannot have non-whitespace substrings of length greater than one with the exception of the following:int(,print(,input()

Comment: ну тогда все правильно - надо подсчитать установленные биты - и вы говорите, что ни 1 ни 2 код не работают?

Comment: @Zhihar ну они работают, но когда я вставляю решение , выбивает ответ ""Forbidden expresion"

Comment: может там просто требование на то, какими функциями можно пользоваться? например функциональное программирование и все должно быть решено в 1 строку и т.п.?

Comment: @Zhihar я могу скрин прикрепить, я если честно сам условие не понял, я же решил задачу и также решал множеством способов, ошибка постоянная  "Forbidden expresion".

Comment: давайте скриншот - посмотрю